# How to check xargs's version?

Tags: osx, xargs

I'm on a Mac and I want to get the xargs's version. I tried `xargs -v`, `xargs --version`, `xargs -h`, `xargs --help`, `xargs`, `man xargs` but still can't find and version related info. How can I get its version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I couldn't find any nice method of obtaining the version info, the only thing I could think of is using `strings` on the `xargs` binary:

```
strings $(which xargs)
$FreeBSD: src/usr.bin/xargs/strnsubst.c,v 1.7 2004/10/18 15:40:47 cperciva Exp $
$FreeBSD: src/usr.bin/xargs/xargs.c,v 1.57 2005/02/27 02:01:31 gad Exp $
@(#)PROGRAM:xargs  PROJECT:shell_cmds-187
[...]
```

In addition to that, you can go to [opensource.apple.com](http://opensource.apple.com/) and navigate to the appropriate source file for your version of OS X. To do that, select the version, then the `shell_cmds` directory and then `xargs`. The files `strnsubst.c` and `xargs.c` contain the same information shown by `strings`.

Comment: Thanks Wieland. I have the exactly same version as you showed in the answer. In your opinion what's the best way to upgrade builtin utilities like xargs?

Comment: Can't find it on homebrew.

Comment: @OgrishMan it would be part of GNU [findutils](http://brewformulas.org/Findutils) I think

Comment: Yes, the findutils formula on homebrew contains (at the moment) version 4.6.0 of the GNU version of xargs.